# MySQL Update query

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I need some help with this MySQL Update

I've got three tables as below.

```
tbl1
id eid quantity
1 3      2
2 4      3

tbl2
tid eid qnty status type
 1  3    1      1         1
 2  3    0      1         0
 3  4    1      1         1
 4  4    0      1         0

tbl3
id tid type 
1  1   1
2  2   0
3  3   1
4  4   0
```

I need an sql update to:

Find X

Find Y

Then Update status in tbl2 to 0 if X - Y > 0

X = tbl1.quantity - sum(tbl2.qnty) where tbl1.eid = tbl2.eid AND type = 1

In other words:

X = tbl1.quantity in that eid - sum(tbl2.qnty) in that eid WHERE type = 1

Thus X for eid 4 = 2 and X for eid 3 = 1

Y = SELECT COUNT(tbl3.id) FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl2.tid = tbl3.tid AND type = 0 GROUP BY tid

Thus tid 2 = 1 and tid 4 = 1

Update status in tble2 to 0 if X - Y > 0

The final result will be that the status for tbl2.tid:4 will be updated to 0 because 2 - 1 = 1

You contribution(s) are appreciated.

Comment: Have been helped from elsewhere, and this is the script: update tbl2 set status = 0 where type = 0 AND eid in 
(select distinct eid from
(
select A.eid, X, Y
from 
(
  SELECT tbl1.eid, (tbl1.quantity - sum(tbl2.qnty)) AS X
  FROM tbl1, tbl2
  WHERE tbl1.eid = tbl2.eid
  AND TYPE =1
  GROUP BY tbl1.eid
) as A
JOIN
(
  SELECT COUNT( tbl3.id ) AS Y, tbl2.eid
  FROM tbl2, tbl3
  WHERE tbl2.tid = tbl3.tid
  AND tbl2.type =0
  GROUP BY tbl2.tid
) as B
ON A.eid = B.eid
HAVING X - Y > 0
) as C 
);

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it right now, so I'm not 100% sure about the syntax, but I think you can do something like this:

update tbl2 
join tbl1 on tbl1.eid = tbl2.eid
join tbl3 on tbl2.tid = tbl3
set status=0 
where tbl2.type=1 and 
      tbl1.quantity - sum(tbl2.qnty) - (select count(tbl3.id) FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl2.tid = tbl3.tid AND type = 0 GROUP BY tid) > 0

Comment: Thanks Rivka for the input. Got: #1111 - Invalid use of group function. Any idea?